# xampp file_get_contents error - file not found

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

```
~
require "config.php";
try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = file_get_contents("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\data\\test1.sql");
    $connection->exec($sql);

    echo "Database and table users created successfully.";
} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
```

My problem is that, I can't seem to get this to work. I have a test1.sql file in the data folder, however it gives me an error, that it can't find it, I've tried multiple things but nothing seems to work, does anyone have any idea ?

error message is:

Warning: file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\test\data\test1.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\install.php on line 13

[picture of the folder I put it in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQi8P.png)

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\test\data\test1.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\install.php on line 13

Comment: Try single, forward slashes in the filename, with a relative path:  `file_get_contents('../../htdocs/test/data/test1.sql');`

Comment: oh my god, it works, THANK YOU!!! I was going insane!

Comment: Hi, I have 1 more problem,  ```Warning: include(../../htdocs/test/public/templates/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\index.php on line 1

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../htdocs/test/public/templates/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\index.php on line 1```

Same for my footer.php, both are in my public/templates folder, this is what i wrote 

```
<?php include '../../htdocs/test/public/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```
same for my header, still doesnt work. :(

Comment: Nevermind, it works, i had to add 1 more "../"